# Vision framework - Detect face on live camera feed, add image over face and record video

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, vision-api

My goal is to process images from camera with Vision framework, add overlay images and record video with overlay images.

One way I found is with AVCaptureSession, with SampleBufferDelegate where in function

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

image by image is processed, added overlay image and passed to AVAssetWriter to create video.

However, problem with this implementation is it can't be run in realtime because app become sluggish.

Is there better and faster way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am also using this approach, and can draw over detected faces, but I am not able to add custom images over detected areas. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, I'm not sure but I think we canceled this project.